# Replace \' with '

Tags: mysql, replace

I had trouble with Magic Quotes before. Now that I've got that fixed, I unfortunately have hundreds of entries already in my database with `\'` instead of just an apostrophe.

This statement doesn't work:

```
UPDATE timeline SET tweet = Replace(tweet,"\'","'")
```

How can I replace all the `\'` with just `'`? Or maybe I could just replace `\` with nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `\` in your UPDATE statement, so change it to this:

```
UPDATE timeline SET tweet = Replace(tweet,'\\','')
```

or

```
UPDATE timeline SET tweet = Replace(tweet,'\\\'','\'')
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d74e9/2